# What (%f) means in C?

Tags: c, types, printf, conversion-specifier

I know that %f means float, althought, I don't know if the brackets make any difference.
I have this:

```
void print_LIST(LIST L){
    CORD *c;
    while(L != NULL){
        c = L->value;
        printf("%d%d",c->col,c->lin);
        printf("(%f) ",distance(c));
        L = L->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It's simply printing a parenthesis around the float number.

Comment: Adding braces to your printf would just add them to the output.

Comment: thanks! I've executed the code, but didn't noticed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything in a format specifier is a conversion specifier (carry special meaning). For example: assuming `i` holds a value of `10`, following statement:

```
 printf ("The value of i is %d", i);
```

will print `The value of i is 10`, so the rest of the string is printed as-is. Following this, in your case

```
 printf ("(%f)", distance(c));
```

will print the `double` value returned by the `distance(c)` function call. Assuming a value 1.23, it will print `(1.23)` (with the parenthesis).